# How to install linux-modules-extra with kernel update

Tags: kernel, 22.04, xubuntu

When upgrading the kernel without `linux-modules-extra-xx-generic`, my computer is losing network access after activating the kernel.

As I have WiFi access only (which is lost after the kernel upgrade), how can I install the package together with the kernel upgrade or upfront?